# custom icon for google maps for android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers

```html
ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers = new returnMapStuff().getStopsList(data);

.
.
.

for(int i=0; i<markers.size();i++){(markers.get(i)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromPath("icons/star.png"));}
```

```html
11-30 20:27:39.559    3026-3026/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62e2288)
11-30 20:27:39.559    3026-3026/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmService: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10050 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2373)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10050 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
            at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1319)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1348)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:448)
            at gsh.c(SourceFile:107)
            at gsh.a(SourceFile:121)
            at gsh.a(SourceFile:182)
            at bek.a(SourceFile:137)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmService.onCreate(SourceFile:209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 20:27:39.563      358-368/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.google.android.gms has crashed too many times: killing!
```

i wonder why my android map crushes when i am trying to implement a custom marker...
how can i use custom icons for markers and what about the file type/size/resolution of the icon?

Comment: Please post the log (when the app crush)

Answer (score 0):

From your log it looks like this is the problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10050 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
```

Either you need to provide the permission in the manifest or if you did it may be a bug in google play servies.

If you do a google search on READ_GSERVICES you will see several items that seem to indicate this is a bug in google play services.

Comment: I include that kind of permission in my manifest...
If it is a bug is there any troubleshooting to fix it???